# Revesse object keys in javascript

Tags: javascript

My response after registration looks as follows:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
    "id": 43,
    "uuid": "afb9fd83-b989-40c6-bb81-210e053fe19a",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z"
    "user": {
        "id": 43,
        "uuid": "588cef19-bbaa-4a91-905e-088d9098a1aa",
        "firstName": "dadadada2",
        "createdAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
    },
}
```

But that does not agree with my DTO class. I would like to get a result:

```
{
    "firstName": "dadadada2",
    "id": 43,
    "uuid": "588cef19-bbaa-4a91-905e-088d9098a1aa",
    "createdAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
    "authentication": {
        "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
        "id": 43,
        "uuid": "afb9fd83-b989-40c6-bb81-210e053fe19a",
        "createdAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-07-29T03:13:29.427Z"
    }
}
```

I tried to combine with types and the Partial method in Typescript, but then I would have to use the word **any** - and I want to avoid this.

How to write functions in JS, who will turn it back?

Comment: `const convertedThing = { firstName: otherThing.user.firstName, ... }`

Comment: this has noting to do with the order of the keys

Answer (score 0):

1- Why not to change your DTO

2- May be you can ask to the Backend dev to change the data sctructure

3- You can just create an object restructured ,
To avoid to create some complex function to manipulate the object keys while keys stay statics.
like :

```
    const compatWithDTO = {
    "firstName": res.user.firstName,
    "id": res.id,
    "uuid": res.uuid,
    "createdAt": res.createdAt,
    "updatedAt": res.updatedAt,
    "authentication" {
        "emailAddress": res.emailAddress,
        "id": res.user.id,
        "uuid": res.user.uuid,
        "createdAt": res.user.createdAt,
        "updatedAt": res.user.updatedAt,
    }
}
```